# remove arrow in DisclosureGroup SwiftUI for iOS 15+

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working wit DisclosureGroup, I have my own 'label' to show, so I do not need the DisclosureGroup arrow or label, my current code is:

```
DisclosureGroup(
    isExpanded: isExpanded,
    content: {
       Text("my content")
    },
    label: {
        HStack {
          // my label 
        }
    )
    .accentColor(.clear)
```

With `.accentColor(.clear)`, it is only possible to hide the arrow. However, if I try to set my label to take up the entire width, the width of the chevron will still be visible. This means that the chevron is never actually removed, it is only hidden

I would need to either remove it or set it to zero to avoid break my padding configuration

[image: in this SS there is the native arrow in blue color]

[image: the arrow with clear color or hidden, but it still take a place]

I would need to have the yellow HStack until the trailing with no spaces

Comment: You are not explaining yourself well, it is difficult to understand what you are looking to do. But, if you are looking to make something appear or not, try using the if statement instead of using `.accentColor(.clear)` or `.hidden()`, for example: 

`if isExpanded { YourView() }`

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your current UI for a clearer understanding of the problem.